# Converting dynamic html content to pdf in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

Converting HTML content from Jodit editor to pdf, having issues with alignment, links and styling issues.

We have tried with libraries like

html2pdf,
html2canvas,
jspdf,
react-pdf,
html-pdf-make,
react-html-pdf,
markdown-pdf,
react-to-pdf,

and we got a close result in html2pdf library. But there are attachment link issue in the pdf that's generated.
Used the code to split the dymanic content to PDF for large pages from the link below
https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/issues/311#issuecomment-877571959
Please let us know any suggesstion or approach to solve the issue

Comment: You can try html3pdf (https://www.npmjs.com/package/html3pdf), which is html2pdf.js with a bunch of bug fixes.  You won't need to use the workaround on issue #311 either, because html3pdf renders each page as its own canvas by default.